# How to make a specific read-only buffer writable?

Tags: minor-mode, read-only-mode

The readonly status of the current buffer can be toggled with `(read-only-mode)` or pressing `C-x C-q` but I intend to make a buffer which is not current, writable. The below is what I am using

```
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*some*")
    (read-only-mode nil))
```

hoping that it would remove the readonly status applied on the buffer '*some*', however it only sets the readonly status again to the buffer. Visiting the buffer and pressing `C-x C-q` does work but that is not what I intend to do, I need to do it remotely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `(read-only-mode -1)`, not `(read-only-mode nil)`.

See the doc string of macro `define-minor-mode` (`C-h f define-minor-mode`) for more info about the argument to a minor-mode function.

And see the doc string of `read-only-mode` for some good info about its use:

> **`read-only-mode`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `simple.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-x C-q`.
>
> `(read-only-mode &optional ARG)`
>
> Change whether the current buffer is read-only.
>
> With prefix argument `ARG`, make the buffer read-only if `ARG` is
>   positive, otherwise make it writable.  If buffer is read-only
>   and `view-read-only` is non-`nil`, enter view mode.
>
> Do not call this from a Lisp program unless you really intend to
>   do the same thing as the `C-x C-q` command, including
>   possibly enabling or disabling View mode.  Also, note that this
>   command works by setting the variable `buffer-read-only`, which
>   does not affect read-only regions caused by text properties.  To
>   ignore read-only status in a Lisp program (whether due to text
>   properties or buffer state), bind `inhibit-read-only` temporarily
>   to a non-`nil` value.